# 90s blue goo movie

Tags: story-identification

Trying to identify a movie that aired on the sci fi channel mid to late 90s. It involved blue goo in a meteorite, electronics and cars not working so no one could leave, the goo made copies of the townspeople, the protagonist dives into the goo at the end to rescue the original people.

Comment: Do you remember any character names or actors who may have featured? Was the protagonist male or female? Did he have friends with him?

Comment: *Evolution* (2001) had blue goo but it didn't stop electronics as I recall.